Flutter Excel Lib Format Tracks
I'm encountering a problem while I'm making a Excel graphic with flutter code the extensions are:
import 'package:excel/excel.dart';
import 'package:gestao_trabalhadores_rfs/SubMenus/subMenuHistAval.dart';
import 'package:syncfusion_flutter_xlsio/xlsio.dart';
import 'package:syncfusion_officechart/officechart.dart' as Chart

in the image you could how the image are.
this is the source code :
final Chart.ChartCollection charts_6 = Chart.ChartCollection(sheet6);
      final Chart.Chart chart_sh6 = charts_6.add();
      chart_sh6.chartType = Chart.ExcelChartType.line;
      chart_sh6.dataRange = sheet6.getRangeByName('A9:${columnLetter}${rowIndex_sh6 -1}');
  
      sheet6.getRangeByName('A10:$columnLetter${rowIndex_sh6 - 1}').rowHeight = 25;
      
      for(int i = 0; i < chart_sh6.series.count; i++) {
      final Chart.ChartSerie serie6 = chart_sh6.series[i];
      serie6.dataLabels.isValue = true;
      }

     chart_sh6.topRow = 5;
     chart_sh6.bottomRow = 25;
     chart_sh6.rightColumn = 20;
     chart_sh6.leftColumn = 6;
     chart_sh6.plotArea;
     chart_sh6.linePattern = Chart.ExcelChartLinePattern.solid;
     chart_sh6.linePattern = Chart.ExcelChartLinePattern.longDashDotDot;
      
     sheet6.charts = charts_6;

I have tried to change the version
